# Excel ActiveX Controls broken, "Can't exit design mode", "Object library invalid"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, activex

So I recently got a new computer with a new installation of:

- Excel 2010 32-bit
- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

There are several strange issues that are happening:

1. Many excel workbook created with activeX controls in the past now give me a compile error "*object library invalid or contains reference to object definitions that could not be found*" or some "*can't exit design mode because Control 'CommandButton1' can not be created*" error. The specific control that is not working is a simple **CommandButton**.
2. Any excel workbook created with activeX controls in the present do not have problems. Some older excel workbooks with activeX work, some do not.
3. Excel workbooks created in the past work fine on most other machines in our company network.
4. If a speadsheet with ActiveX controls is copy-pasted into a new workbook, the controls begin to work again.
5. If I click "view code" on the commandbutton, the VBA window will create new button code with a new subroutine name.

I know lots of questions have been asked about this subject but the solutions don't seem to be working for me.

1. EXD files have been deleted.
2. Microsoft office has been reinstalled
3. Uninstalling Microsoft security updates isn't an option. Windows is fully updated to Dec 2016.
4. A lot of old solutions are from 3-6 years ago and may be outdated.
5. I've tried "save-as" on affected workbooks. This does not work.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check the product version of MCOMCTL.OCX on your machine. Now check the same of one of the machine's where the Activex Controls is working. I bet they are different.

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Office, or 32-bit? Do your VBA Project's references look complete ( a missing ActiveX Control Library will show as Broken/Missing). Which controls do you know are in the workbook? You may need the Common Controls, DatePicker or Calendar Controls, which aren't installed, by default, beyond Office 2007.

Comment: What happens if you save the existing workbook with a new name? Are you using XLS, XLSM, or XLSB formats?

Comment: Typo Correction : its `MSCOMCTL.OCX`

Comment: @cyboashu I checked a coworker's machine and the version of MSCOMCTL.OCX is the same at 6.1.98.46

Comment: hmm.. then I am out, look into pointer given by Thunderframe.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same with the same setup as yours, my solution was to uninstall updates, I dont know any other solution but would be interested as well.

Comment: To improve your answer: which updates did you uninstall, and how did you uninstall them?

Comment: I uninstalled all of them an went back to the original install from the install package of OFFICE